# Launching a Powerapp using Edge from a batch file on full screen

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line, microsoft-edge, powerapps

I am trying to launch a Powerapp using MS Edge to display on a screen. I have a batch file that needs to run every 6 hours. I need to close Edge and then relaunch the powerapp link, but the problem I am having is that when the app is relaunched it is opened on a minimised window. I need to have the powerapp displaying full screen without any Edge menus or anything. This is my code at the moment. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
start msedge
taskkill /F /IM msedge.exe
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c "start microsoft-edge:https://apps.powerapps.com/play/{app_link}&hidenavbar=true" --disable-extensions --new-window --start-fullscreen --disable-popup-blocking
```

Comment: Thanks @KJ what does "FullMetalEdge" do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test your code, Edge is open in maximin size but Edge menus still exist. If you want to open Edge in full screen without any menus, you can use [Kiosk Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-configure-kiosk-mode#use-kiosk-mode-features).

You can add `--kiosk` flag to enable kiosk mode in Edge, the sample code is like below. It can achieve what you want:

```
start msedge
taskkill /F /IM msedge.exe
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c "start msedge.exe --kiosk --disable-extensions --new-window --start-fullscreen --disable-popup-blocking https://apps.powerapps.com/play/{app_link}"
```

Comment: For an even cleaner look, add `hidenavbar=true` to the PowerApps URL. This will hide all the cruft.